# Modify part of an array

Tags: c++

I want to modify elements in an array from index A to B.

Example: I have an array [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. I want to increment elements between index 1 to 2 by 1 such that the array will be [0, 1, 1, 0, 0] at the end of the operation. Is there any better way to do this rather than looping through the array and modifying them one by one?

I am going to apply this to a big array so it would be best if there is a way to do this without the use of loops.

Sample:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // initialisation
    int arr[5];
    int first_indx = 1, last_indx = 2;
    fill(arr, arr + 5, 0);
    cout << "Initial: \n";
    for (int a : arr) {
        cout << a << ", ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    // operation to modify array
    for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
        if (first_indx <= b && b <= last_indx) {
            arr[b]++;
        }
    }
    // output
    cout << "After modification: \n";
    for (int c : arr) {
        cout << c << ", ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Initial:
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
After modification:
0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
```

Comment: Loop over the indexes you want to modify instead of the whole range.

Comment: i think i should rephrase the question hold on

Comment: Why? I do not understand why someone vote you down. Question is well phrased has complete information. Your beginner skills is not a reason to down vote your question.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to loop only within the range to modify than looping among the whole array.

```
    // operation to modify array
    for (int b = first_indx; b <= last_indx; b++) {
        arr[b]++;
    }
```

Comment: I was faster by 5 seconds :)

Answer (score 3):

Why you iterating over whole thing?

```cpp
    for (int b = first_indx ; b <= last_indx; b++) {
        arr[b]++;
    }
```

**Note**:
I've got feeling you are solving some online task which is more challenging then you think (there are many ranges which do this modification). Your brutal force solution will not score maximum result, even when you applied fix from answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop and as others pointed out you need not iterate the whole range just to skip elements out of the desired range. A different way to achieve the same is already present in your code:

```
fill(arr, arr + 5, 0);
```

This fills elements from the first (`arr` decays to a pointer to the first element here) till the last (`arr + 5`) with `0`. To assign a differnt value in a different range you can use the same algorithm:

```
int start = 1;
int end = 3;
std::fill(arr + start, arr + end, 1);
```

Make sure the range is valid (ie not out of bounds of the array). Note that I used a half open range, ie `start` is included, `end` is not included, because it is common convention to do so.